# How to figure out what causes random Windows hangs?

Tags: windows-8

It has been 2 full days that my computer has random 1second hangs... Even the mouse won't move, sound hangs too while listening to music.

I have made absolutely no software changes, there may have been automatic updates. I have checked my process list, and the hangs happen even when resources taken are a lot lower than my normal activities. I have tried closing all the programs I could and it is still happening. A virus scan did not result in any positives, as usual.

What else did I forget to check?

> As of today, the freezes and hangs are not happening anymore. The only
>   thing that happened is a GPU driver update that ran automatically
>   before I could find free time to dig deeper.

Comment: I would suggest using Process Explorer and make the difference highlight time long enough that you can easily see any processes that might be quickly starting and stopping.

Comment: MS SysInternals *SysMon*, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348, logs all process creation in *detail*, but will put a lot of data in the Event Log.

Comment: Also a good option to catch short lifetime processes. I generally prefer process explorer because there is a better chance of catching resource usage information for the process.

Comment: maybe you have a DPC/ISR issue: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - The proposed duplicate is specific to that hardware, running Windows 7, and focuses on the diagnostics that OP ran.  That might be a good starting point, but are you comfortable that it is the source for the "complete" answer for all other computers?

Comment: I am very sorry but all of a sudden, the hangs disappeared. The only thing that changed since it started is a GPU driver update.

Answer (score 0):

Random freezing/hanging is frequently caused by a software or hardware issue with the GPU. The GPU driver update seems to have fixed the problem.